# How to remove images from cache on Windows 8 Phone app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

From what I read, whenever you assign an image to a XAML element via its Source property, there is some sort of smart caching going on.

Unfortunately for my app (Flash Cards), I am dynamically switching the image.Source property every time the user flicks (aka swipes) the card in front of him/her. It's the same XAML element, but its Source property gets replaced every time.

I have 4 sets of Flash Cards, and the app holds on just fine if I pick up to 3 sets at a time, but if I pick 4 sets when the count reaches around the 52nd or 54th card, the memory use surpasses 150MB (which is the set limit) and my test device (Nokia Lumia 520) crashes with an out of memory error.

After profiling the app, I pinned down the issue to be caused by the image loading event.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you use as a Source, BitmapImage or WriteableBitmap? Do you create a new image every time the user flicks?

Comment: Yes to both. I use BitmapImage, and I create a new image every time the user flicks (I translated it to Spanish, so I have images with the English and Spanish images).

Comment: Could you share some relevant code? BitmapImage caching can sometimes be prevented if you try setting UriSource to 'null' before it goes out of scope. Can you try doing that?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, nulling the things you won't be needing anymore out can be helpful when working with images.

Considering you're using a BitmapImage and create a new one every time, I would try setting the bitmap image UriSource to null

```
bmpImage.UriSource = null;
```

before nulling the BitmapImage itself

```
bmpImage = null;
```

before the BitmapImage object you created goes out of scope and before you create a new one and assign it to Image as source. (of course)

In case you're using multiple Image objects, I'd set their Source to null, too. (for example, when creating some complex image overlays in code behind etc.)

That helped me a lot when working with BitmapImages, especially in background task.

Comment: I had to dig deeper in the code (I wrote this more than 6 months ago), and I realized that when creating the FlashDeck object, I initialize the FlashCard objects with the BitmapImage object for each card selected.

So at runtime, the only thing I am doing is setting the XAML Source property to the current FlashCard object's BitmapImage, and it appears that it's the XAML portion of the code which is causing the overload, because the memory profile chart didn't show any spikes after initializing the FlashCad deck.

Comment: So, in my case there is really no point at which my image goes out of scope because it is immediately replaced with a new one. I just keep reusing the XAML resource over and over (I have one card on top, and one under that shows the next card, and I just swap image sources to give the illusion of a real card deck in action).